# Displaying a DateTime + 1 year

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, razor, code-first

My goal is to get pull the latest date in training and and display it with 1 year added to it. I am using code fisrt and ASP.net MVC. My first table is called Person and it contains all basic if on a person. The second table is called Session and it contains all the previous dates and individual has been trained. Sessions.cs looks like this
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

```
namespace CleryAct.Models
{
    public class Session
    {

        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [StringLength(9, MinimumLength = 9, ErrorMessage = "Rocket Number must be longer than 9 characters.")]
        public string rockets { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime training { get; set; }

        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The code for my view was generated my adding a new scaffolding item to my view and linking it to the persons database. I need +1 year to be displayed below but I am getting this error with the current code.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.csa)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.lname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.fname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.rockets)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sessions.ElementAtOrDefault(0).training.AddYears(1))*
        </td>
        <td>
```

The variable is a DateTime. I am using Razor MVC

Comment: And the error is … … …?

Comment: You mean you just want another property on your model, something like `public DateTime trainingEnd => training.AddYears(1)` and add an annotation to that?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Comment: Is your Sessions collection of item empty ?

Comment: No, My Sessions has all of the previous training dates. I have test values in there right now.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to do it with out adding to the model. I currently have it displaying the date I want to add 1 year to. I just can not get it to add one to that dates year.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `DisplayFor()` only likes variables without additional code attached.

Try this instead:

```
<td>
    @item.Sessions.ElementAtOrDefault(0).training.AddYears(1)
</td>
```

Comment: This did not work. It error with something very similar to the first error. I don't remember what it was.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @{
                if (item.Sessions.Count > 0)
                {
                    int year = item.Sessions.ElementAt(0).training.Year;
                    ++year;
                    <div>@item.Sessions.ElementAt(0).training.Month.ToString("D2")-@item.Sessions.ElementAt(0).training.Day.ToString("D2")-@year.ToString()</div>

                }
            }
```

Comment: Like I said in my answer, just don't use `DisplayFor()`. It looks like you had other issues with your code as well which is why it did not work.